# How to connect Android app to AWS IotCore by X509 certificate

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to connect AwsIotCore by x509 cert
follow the demo of the java application it has no problem
but when I pick up this code to use in the android app
my application can not connect to IotCore
I know AWS suggest using Cognito pool to connect the android app to IotCore
So, can the android application be connected to AWS IotCore by x509 cert?
If the answer is no please let me know why?

Thanks for support